# Accent in javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, diacritics

I got a hard time with accent (hey i'm french, nobody is perfect !)
both problem in php and javascript.. here is the code :

**in php :**

```
 $message = "";
 $message .= "Bonjour!". "\r\n";
 $message .= "Je désire m'inscrire à la liste d'envoi pour recevoir le bulletin de la Fondation Martin-Matte par courriel.". "\r\n";
 $message .= "Merci"."\r\n";
 $message = utf8_encode($message);
```

the encode function produce : 
`Bonjour!, Je dÃ©sire ......` not good !

HOW to encode properly a string with accent ?

---

and in javascript : `alert ("l'adresse de courriel : "+ email +" est bien ajouté à la liste d'envoit, merci");`
produce a � caracter...

what should i do ???? help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dÃ©sire` is caused by unicode (UTF-8) characters being displayed as ANSI. The � character is caused by ANSI characters (above 127) being displayed as UTF-8. 
When your PHP outputs UTF-8 character, you should also send a Content-Encoding header to notify the client that the data is UTF-8. It is recommended to output this encoding in the heading of your HTML file as well.

I think you can save javascript files as UTF-8 without problems.

Comment: i need more infos... what is the line to add/modify ?

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` in PHP. Optionally also `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` if you want the user to be able to save the HTML and retain charset information. JavaScript files are, unless overridden (which is unreliable), interpreted as being in the same charset as the document that includes them.

Answer (score 1):

To convert ANSI to UTF-8 or UTF-8 to ANSI, open the file with Notepad and use `Save as`. this opens a box where it's possible to choose UTF-8 or ANSI.

I did it and my problem was solved in a second.